# Show message box if value not found

Tags: excel, vba

A fantastic user has already helped me to develop a code to look up in sheet"Reqs" column B, a value the user has input into sheet "Home" G11 (a reference number), and then enter the current date & time into a cell in sheet"Reqs", 21 columns along from the found value.

Now I would like to modify the code, to both

a) enter the value from sheet"Home" G12 into the cell in sheet"Reqs" adjacent to the just-input date (one column along, same row).

and 
b) if the input reference number is not found, show a msgbox (in sheet"Home") saying "number not found"

For b) I tried to simply add an "Else: msgbox "Number not found", but this gives the error, "Else without If", but I already have an If...

Many thanks

```
Sub CloseJob()
    Dim temp As Range
    Set temp = 
Sheets("Reqs").Columns("B").Find(What:=Sheets("Home").Range("G11").Value, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    'if found
    If Not temp Is Nothing Then temp.Offset(0, 21) = Date
```

There are other actions after this, but they work OK

Comment: Can you show the code that's not working? I don't see any `Else`

Comment: Put the part after Then (temp.offset....) in the next line and then use Else it will work.

Comment: Hi @ImranMalek, yes that worked for the messagebox.  Can you help me at all with part a) please?

Comment: @scamparella It should be temp.Offset(0, 22) = Sheets("Home").range("G12").value

Comment: WOW!  thank you so much @ImranMalek!   You have a place in the heaven of your choosing ;-)

Comment: @scamparella You're welcome and Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the exact error, or seeing what you attempted I can't be entirely sure, but it may have came down to formatting of the syntax.

Give this a try:

```
If Not temp Is Nothing Then 
    temp.Offset(0, 21) = Date
Else
    MsgBox("Number Not Found")
End If
```

If you still have an error, let us know what the error is and we can go from there

For your first question go ahead and try something like this:

```
Sub Test()
Worksheets("Home").Cells(12, 7).Copy

'You mentioned 21 columns along from the FoundValue, so I added a variable to the column argument of the cells function
'that you can change as needed

Worksheets("Reqs").Cells(12, FoundValue + 21).Paste

End Sub
```

Keep in mind the Cells function takes an argument of Rows, Columns -- so make sure what I wrote is consistent with what you need. Always try on test data first!

Comment: Hi @Dylan L, yes that worked thank you - are you able to help me with part a) ?

Comment: Added an edit for you that should help you on part a!

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the part after Then in your code , currently it is ending the IF statement which is not what you want.

Put your code in following formatting and see if this works.

```
If Not temp Is Nothing Then 
  temp.Offset(0, 21) = Date
  temp.Offset(0, 22) = Sheets("Home").range("G12").value 

Else
...
End If
```